# No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-security

I am having some issues setting up spring security
It seems it cant find the springSecurityFilterChain bean
My spring security config:

```
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="user1" password="1234" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>

</authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
           /WEB-INF/config/security-config.xml
        </param-value>
   </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
             /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My xml file locations:

[image]

I think it can't find the /WEB-INF/config/security-config.xml

Answer (score 1):

I think that the reason of your problem can be in that your xml configuration file for spring security isn't loaded when you start your web app.

To fix this you should specify all your XML config files in `web.xml` like that:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml, /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

If you have your config files in `classpath` (not WEB-INF folder or it's subfolders) then you can specify list of config files in such way;

```
<param-value>
    classpath:applicationContext.xml,
    classpath:spitter-security.xml
</param-value>
```

And also you need to add special listener that will load your config files:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```